# Design pattern Observer aplicado em eventos

Tags: c#, java, orientação-a-objetos, design-pattern, observer-pattern

Estou estudando os padrões de projeto e estou tentando aplicar uma situação real para eles.

E um exemplo que fiz foi no cenário de eventos:

Nesse cenário todo evento tem os participantes pra cadastrar.

Logo, para isso, implementei o padrão **Observer**, toda vez que a data do evento mudar, ele notifica os seus participantes mandando um e-mail. A forma que implementei não vem ao caso, o *design pattern* **Observer** poderia ser aplicado nesse caso?

Comment: Tem o código que criou?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O entendimento geral é esse. Nada impede de fazer isto. Mas o padrão Observer é um mecanismo e não uma regra de negócio como você utilizou. Se mostrasse um código daria para avaliar melhor.

De fato o padrão Observer implementa justamente eventos, mas não este tipo de evento que você está falando, não eventos sociais e sim eventos de computador.

Da maneira que você criou, quem são os assinantes? Pessoas reais que você não tem controle algum? Isto não me parece ser o padrão Observer. Neste padrão os assinantes costumam ser outras partes da aplicação que precisam ser notificadas. De uma maneira geral ele é um padrão de projeto criado para uso com orientação à objeto.

Exemplos:

- Um arquivo foi modificado no sistema de arquivos
- Uma propriedade preço foi modificada em uma classe produto
- Um click foi dado em botão
- Recebeu uma informação da rede
- Um objeto visual do jogo se encontrou com outro objeto (acertou o alvo)
- Uma atualização no banco de dados ocorreu

Se podemos transportar o conceito de Observer do computador para fora dele eu não sei. O que você está fazendo é algo parecido com o padrão definido mas me parece uma variante que não condiz com a definição formal do padrão. Me parece mais um *observer-like*.

Você pode usar a lógica que você quiser para alcançar seu objetivo. O que posso dizer é que se você está preocupado se está implementando um padrão de projeto ou não, está com a preocupação errada.

Padrões de projeto dependem de implementação, você pode alcançar seu objetivo de outras formas (provavelmente piores) onde caberia um padrão de projeto.

[image: Diagrama Observer]

Fonte: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

Neste diagrama quem são seus `notify()`? Os e-mails dos participantes como você chamou? Me parece estranho. Eu acho que o padrão não foi criado para isto.

No fundo o que importa se você está usando o padrão ou não? Sua implementação está fazendo tudo o que deveria fazer de forma correta e eficiente?

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: O notify vai mandar um e-mail para cada Observer, que no caso é o participante, da classe Participante. Isso não seria o Observer? No mais, muito obrigado. Fiz isso utilizando o intuito, mas realmente não devo estar utilizando o padrão. Tipo, você dá esse exemplo "Uma propriedade preço foi modificada em uma classe produto". Não seria a mesma lógica? Quando a data do evento for alterada, ele notifica os observers?

Comment: Sem ver o código fica difícil avaliar com precisão. Se a resposta foi útil você pode votar nela e aceitá-la também se achar que te atendeu. Veja o [tour].

Comment: Estou sem o projeto aqui. Mas fiz seguindo o tutorial abaixo. O que você acha da abordagem desse site? http://blog.camilolopes.com.br/serie-designpattern-observer/  No site o Observer é o painel, no meu caso, o participante que tem como atributo o e-mail. E lá no método notificar(update) da classe Painel, ele iria mandar um e-mail. E aí? O que acha dessa abordagem?

Comment: Aí parece tudo ok, mas não sei como você implementou. Você colocou as *tags* Java e C#. Em Java eu faria de um jeito, em C# em faria de outro.

Comment: A implementação é igualzinha. Só que nesse caso o Painel tem um nome. No meu caso é o Participante, a "pessoa". E essa pessoa tem um nome e email. E na parte de notificar eu uso um comando de enviar e-mail para o participante, que vai ser this.Email, já que estou na classe do participante. Entendeste? e aí, realmente está certo?

Comment: Deve estar, mas não sei, uma coisa é descrever, outra é fazer.