# Porque nova instancia da ActionListener recebe um parenteses e um ;(ponto e vírgula) no final?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, tipo-anônimo

Nunca vi esse tipo de estrutura de código na instancia, o que isso faz? A classe `ActionListener` para instanciá-la é preciso colocá-la assim:

```
ActionListener trataEventos = new ActionListener(){
     public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e){
     conteudo += e.getActionCommand();
     campoDoFormularioHTML.setMember("value", "" + conteudo);
   }
  };
```

É semelhante a fazer como um método, por que precisa criar a instância dessa forma?

Segue completo:

```
   public class Teclado extends Applet{

   public String conteudo = "";
   public String formulario;
   public String campo;
   public JSObject campoDoFormularioHTML; 

   public void init(){
     formulario = getParameter("formulario");
     campo = getParameter("campo"); 
     ActionListener trataEventos = new ActionListener(){
     public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e){
     conteudo += e.getActionCommand();
     campoDoFormularioHTML.setMember("value", "" + conteudo);
   }
  };
```

Comment: Explique melhor, de que parênteses está falando?

Comment: Isso é porque você está fazendo uma chamada a uma classe anônima quando deu um new em ActionListener.

Comment: Classe anônima isso existe?

Comment: [Classes aninhadas: o que são e quando usar?](http://blog.caelum.com.br/classes-aninhadas-o-que-sao-e-quando-usar/)

Comment: [Classes anônimas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html), elas tem sua razão de ser porém em java sempre foram usadas na maioria das vezes para tapar o buraco que era a falta de suporte a [lambdas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) antes da versão 8.

Comment: Certo @DiegoF vou estudar isso. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando a gente mantém o código organizado, com indentação correta fica mais fácil entender:

```
ActionListener trataEventos = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
        conteudo += e.getActionCommand();
        campoDoFormularioHTML.setMember("value", "" + conteudo);
    }
};
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Syntax/MatchBraces.java).

Note que a última chave fecha o início do método `ActionListener()`. Todo bloco de código que é aberto precisa ser fechado.

O ponto e vírgula está apenas encerrando uma linha comum, como é feito sempre. Note que o bloco de código faz parte de apenas uma linha de código iniciado em `ActionListener trataEventos = new ActionListener() {`. Esta é uma linha que declara uma variável e atribuí um valor para ela. No caso este valor é um bloco de código de uma [classe anônima](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) (a classe só existirá aí e não poderá ser usada como tipo em outros lugares). Dentro desta classe tem a definição de um método.

Neste caso é necessário porque está criando um evento. É uma forma de implementação do [padrão Observer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/36655/101) ([outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45020/101)). É algo que precisa reagir a algo que acontece na aplicação. Este algo é uma ação concreta que deve ser definido por algum código, um método, por isso cria-se uma classe que contenha este método que será chamado quando o evento ocorrer. O Java 8 introduziu um [recurso novo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101) que evita a criação de uma classe só para isto.

Vou escrever um código aqui que não é o correto mas ajudaria entender o que ocorre naquela **única** linha de código:

```
 class ClasseTemporaria implements ActionListener {
     public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
         conteudo += e.getActionCommand();
         campoDoFormularioHTML.setMember("value", "" + conteudo);
     }
 }

 ActionListener trataEventos = new ClasseTemporaria();
```

Não vou entrar em maiores detalhes porque este assunto é um pouco avançado e pelo histórico da AP acho que mais informações para explicar o recurso da classe anônima e o uso específico, neste caso, antes de entender outras coisas mais básicas vão só atrapalhar.

Comment: Obrigada, entendi.

Answer (score 0):

O nome disto é classe anônima.

ActionListener é uma interface, então ela precisa ser implementada através de uma classe concreta. Quando uma interface precisa ser implementada como uma classe interna em um local exclusivo, em vez de criar uma nova classe, utilizasse uma classe anônima.

Este artigo explica melhor:
http://www.devmedia.com.br/classes-anonimas-e-aninhadas-em-java/31167

Comment: E o `;`(ponto-e-virgula)?

Comment: Porque esta instanciando o objeto, é como se fosse ActionListenner trataEventos = new ClasseActionListenner();

Comment: : ) okay. Obrigada.