# Adicionar funções em botoes de aplicação gráfica

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Estou com dificuldades para colocar funções para botões em java. Alguém pode ajudar?

Segue o código:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Insets;


import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Painel extends JPanel{

    private static final Color COR_FUNDO = Color.RED;
    private int largura;
    private int altura;

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();


    public Painel(int altura, int largura){
        this.altura = altura;
        this.largura = largura;
        botaoAdicionar();
        botaoRemover();
        botaoConsultar();
        botaoPesquisar();

    }


    public void botaoAdicionar(){
        Botao adicionar = new Botao();
        adicionar.setText("Adicionar ator");
        adicionar.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        adicionar.setMargin(new Insets(2, 10, 2, 14));
        adicionar.setFont(new Font("Linux libertine G", Font.BOLD, 14));
        add(adicionar);


    }

    public void botaoRemover(){
        Botao remover = new Botao();
        remover.setText("Remover Ator");
        remover.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        remover.setFont(new Font("Linux libertine G", Font.BOLD, 14));
        remover.setLocation(200, 200);
        remover.setEnabled(true);
        add(remover);

    }

    public void botaoConsultar(){
        Botao consultar = new Botao();
        consultar.setText("Consultar elenco");
        consultar.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        consultar.setFont(new Font("Linux libertine G", Font.BOLD, 14));
        add(consultar);
    }

    public void botaoPesquisar(){
        JButton pesquisar = new JButton("Pesquisar Ator");
        pesquisar.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        pesquisar.setFont(new Font("Linux libertine G", Font.BOLD, 14));
        add(pesquisar);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint (Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(COR_FUNDO);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, largura, altura);

    }
```

Comment: Amanda a resposta abaixo lhe atendeu?

Answer (score 2):

Para adicionar ações em botões(supondo que sejam JButtons pelo seu código), basta adicionar um [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        //aqui você adiciona o código com o a ação
       //que será executada quando o botão for clicado
    }
});
```

Para casos onde o trecho da ação for um pouco mais complexo, você pode criar um método a parte e apenas chamá-lo dentro da [classe anônima](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/121163/porque-nova-instancia-da-actionlistener-recebe-um-parenteses-e-um-ponto-e-v%C3%ADrg/121165#121165)(passar o `ActionEvent` como parâmetro é opcional para o caso de você for fazer uso de alguma informação do componente clicado):

```
jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        //chama o método com a ação do botão
        ButtonHandler(evt);
    }
});

//...

private void ButtonHandler(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   //ação do botão em um método desmembrado
}
```

**Referências:**

[How to Write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

[Trabalhando com ActionListener e KeyListener em Java](http://www.devmedia.com.br/javalisteners-trabalhando-com-actionlistener-e-keylistener-em-java/31850)

Comment: Seria interessante explicar o motivo do downvote, para que possa corrigir o que supostamente não está legal na resposta.