# Como uma função é executa automaticamente sem ser chamada?

Tags: javascript, funções, design-pattern, eventos

Eu posso criar uma função em JavaScript e chamá-la da seguinte forma:

```js
funcaoTeste = function() 
{
 console.log('Ola funcao teste');
};

funcaoTeste();
```

Para executar a função eu preciso chamar ela `funcaoTeste()`, entretendo, as vezes eu me deparo com códigos JavaScript em que uma função é executada mas eu não vejo onde ela é chamada.

Veja este exemplo prático de ilustração:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    document.getElementById('form-exemplo').onsubmit = function (event) 
    {
        if ( CPF.validate(document.getElementById('cpf').value) !== true ) 
        {
            alert("CPF invalido");
            return false;
        }
    };
};
```

O código acima é referente a este formulário:

```
<form method="post" id="form-exemplo">
    <label for="nome">Nome </label>
    <input type="text" id="nome" placeholder="Digite o nome" required>

    <label for="cep">CEP </label>       
    <input type="text" id="cep" placeholder="Digite o CEP" required pattern="\d{5}-?\d{3}">

    <label for="cpf">CPF </label>
    <input type="text" id="cpf" placeholder="Digite o CPF" required>

    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Repare que as funções `onload()` e `onsubmit()` foram declaradas, porém não existe a chamada delas no *script*. Parece que isso ocorre de uma forma automática que eu desconheço.

## Perguntas

1. Como uma função é executa automaticamente sem ser chamada?
2. Quem é responsável por executar as funções `onload()` e
   `onsubmit()`?

Comment: São executadas nos eventos `load` e `submit` respectivamente.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O *engine* do navegador fará isso. Ele é quem controla toda execução e chama alguns eventos.

O `onload` é um evento, então quando você joga uma função nele, quando ocorrer a carga da página o *engine* chamará esta função.

O mesmo ocorre com o `onsubmit` que é um evento a ser chamado sempre que iniciar a submissão do formulário.

O sistema de eventos é muito útil em todo sistema onde você quer quer controlar a execução, mas dar alguns ganchos (*hooks*) para que o usuário deste sistema, no caso o programador do *script* possa personalizar alguma ação específica quando algo ocorre.

No fundo é um [*callback*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/101).

Veja [O que é a Programação Orientada a Eventos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80601/101). Não considero JS sozinho orientado a eventos, mas todo o *engine* é.

[Como funciona em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56957/101).

No fundo eventos aplicam o [padrão de projeto Observer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/36655/101). Como pode ser visto em [Design pattern Observer aplicado em eventos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45020/101).

Também é útil entender o que é [inversão de controle](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21319/101) que é o que ocorre com o *engine* JS, a maioria das GUIs e outras aplicações do tipo [*framework*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Isso só ocorre com eventos, certo?

Comment: Ocorre com *callbacks* em geral. Não estou tão por dentro do JS para afirmar isto, mas eu acho que que todos os *callbacks* padrões do JS em navegadores são eventos.