# O que é um manipulador de eventos?

Tags: terminologia, eventos

Já li [o que é um evento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/207571/66203), mas então vi que existem os manipuladores de evento, *event handler*.

- O que é um *event handler*?
- Pra que servem e onde são usados?
- Existem em todas linguagens?

Comment: Só pra citar um detalhe `handler` é traduzido para português como "manipulador" e notará essa palavra em muitos lugares da programação, não só eventos, então eu diria que tudo que tem eventos e estes eventos podem ser interceptados são considerados como uma manipulação, então se a linguagem permite interagir quando um evento é registrado/adicionado então terá um handler :) - Só opinião.

Comment: Gosto da tradução de "handler" como "tratador", porque é uma tradução correta e adequada, como em _"let me handle this" ("deixe-me tratar/cuidar disto")_ , e é o que o _handler_ faz, ele trata ou cuida do evento, no sentido de assumir a responsabilidade por lidar com o mesmo. Acho mais precisa porque o objeto do evento (ou mesmo se considerarmos a entidade do evento em si) em geral é um sinal de que algo precisa ser feito, e não necessariamente um item a ser manipulado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Grosso modo é a ação que deve ser executada quando um evento deve ser disparado. Em geral é um método ou função com uma [assinatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) específica que será chamado pelo evento. Ele é um [*callback*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/101).

Como é um manipulador de evento, é ele que responde quando um evento é disparado, é ele que manipula o evento e faz alguma coisa.

Eles costumam estar ligados a objetos que precisam ser notificados de eventos que ocorram com outros objetos para exercer alguma ação.

A forma exata de implementação pode variar. Alguns podem ser criados pela linguagem, biblioteca ou manualmente. A API que gera o evento determinará como precisa ser feito.

As demais perguntas não podem ser respondidas e são informações irrelevantes. Pelo menos na forma perguntada.

Veja mais:

- [Design pattern Observer aplicado em eventos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45020/101)
- [O que é a Programação Orientada a Eventos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80601/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre event e delegate?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56957/101)
- [O que é um evento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/207571/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).