# As lambdas e streams do Java 8 trazem mais benefícios além da concisão?

Tags: java, expressões-lambda, java-8, programação-funcional, stream

Os únicos benefícios que percebo nas *lambdas* e *streams* do Java 8 são economia de código e, conforme o caso, expressar melhor a intenção do autor. É só isso mesmo?

Existe algum exemplo de código que usa um desses recursos e fica melhor não apenas no sentido de deixar o código mais curto, em comparação ao código pré-Java 8?

Algum benefício extra como deixar o código menos engessado ou mais fácil de manter ou extensível?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mais benefícios em relação a que? Em criar classes inteiras para simular o mesmo resultado? Afinal a *lambda* usa a infraestrutura de classes para funcionar. Então a concisão é provavelmente o maior ganho. E isso não é pouco.

Eu diria que junto com a concisão vem a simplificação do código, faz tudo ser definido em um lugar só. E simplificação ajuda evitar erros que poderiam ser cometidos se tivesse que fazer tudo na mão.

O uso de classes anônimas ajuda um pouco pelo menos ficar tudo ali onde está sendo consumido, mas ainda é código demais, ilegível demais, perde-se no fluxo.

Declarar melhor a intenção é outro ponto muito importante. E isso não é pouco. Quer mais que isso?

A *lambda* em si não dá mais poder ou flexibilidade porque tudo pode ser feito sem ela.

É aquela coisa, se não quiser a concisão, a simplificação e a robustez, então programe em Assembly :) Tudo que existe em linguagens de alto nível é sobre concisão, simplificação, robustez e dar a oportunidade do autor declarar melhor sua intenção.

## Estilo funcional

O seu uso faz mudar um pouco o estilo de programação e os padrões adotados. Ela permite melhores abstrações sem complicações. O código tende a ser [mais declarativo e menos imperativo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81854/101).

Java foi uma linguagem que nasceu um pouco defendendo que o imperativo não é bom, só que o declarativo é o que contrapõe o imperativo, não a orientação a objeto. [Programação funcional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/127121/101) é mais concisa e *lambda* é um conceito fundamental deste paradigma. Esse é um ganho significativo para expressividade e legibilidade, mas tem a ver com a intenção.

## Onde é usado

Um exemplo é que você não precisa criar uma classe nova para personalizar um comportamento, desde que a classe original suporte isso o próprio objeto pode personalizar o que fazer em determinada situação. Nesse ponto a *lambda* pode funcionar como um método virtual. De fato o mecanismo é idêntico. É você ter um ponteiro para uma função que ainda será definida no objeto, só que a *lambda* permite o consumidor fazer o que quiser, mas é igual a um método virtual. Isso pode ser bom ou ruim, nem sempre é o que se deseja.

Outro ponto é quando precisa chamar um método em uma classe que não tem relação direta com herança, como faz isso? Normalmente cria-se uma classe que pode ser abstrata ou interface que mantenha um contrato para este método e uma classe concreta derivada desta é criada para ser consumida por outra classe que espera a classe ou interface base, aí ela sabe que pode chamar o método desejado que ele existirá nessa classe. Normalmente é muita complicação, muito código para obter o resultado desejado.

Imagine ter que criar uma classe toda vez que precise de um *stream* (odeio esse nome, confunde com [outra coisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227339/101), apesar de ser o mesmo conceito). Certamente esse é um enorme beneficiário. Com isso pode-se criar [eventos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45020/101) e simplificar a criação de [observáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/36655/101). O que foi inclusive o estopim para a criação do C#. Eu sempre soube que um dia Java teria isso para poder sobreviver, houve uma queda de braço por egos no caso.

## Outros ganhos

Eu poderia dizer que a abstração melhor é um ganho extra não citado na pergunta, mas na verdade sempre pôde fazer. As pessoas não faziam porque não era conciso. E um pouco também porque, em geral, seguem receitas de bolo e antes das *lambdas* raramente alguém fazia uma receita mostrando como fazer desta forma. Por isso que eu sempre digo para todo mundo aprender todos conceitos, fundamentos, paradigmas, aprender linguagens "estranhas" só para ver jeitos diferentes de fazer o que deseja.

Então não sei nem se há tanto ganho na expressão da intenção, isso sempre pôde fazer, a concisão é que incentivou fazer melhor.

Então se o ganho basicamente são os conhecidos pelo AP e que ele deve conhecer códigos que dão mais concisão e melhor intenção, então não tenho exemplos de código a postar.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).