# ForEach com lambda que retorna a soma dos itens iterados

Tags: java, expressões-lambda, foreach, java-8, stream

Estou tentando iterar sobre uma `List` chamada `produtos` de objetos chamados `Produto`, usando o `forEach`, para obter a soma dos valores desses produtos usando a função lambda do `forEach`. Mas não encontro a sintaxe correta pra fazer isso.

Vejam como está meu código:

```
    private double getValorVenda(){
       double valor=0;

        produtos.forEach(produto -> {
            produto.getValor(Venda.class);
        });
        return valor;
    }
}
```

Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Por que não usar um `for` simples?

```
private double getValorVenda() {
    double valor = 0.0;
    for (Produto produto : produtos) {
        valor += produto.getValor(Venda.class);
    }
    return valor;
}
```

O método [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) serve para "fazer algo" com cada elemento da lista, tanto que ele recebe como parâmetro um [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) (uma operação que faz algo com o elemento e não retorna nada).

Se você tentar fazer o mesmo algoritmo acima com `forEach`, o código não compila:

```
produtos.forEach(p -> {
    valor += p.getValor(Venda.class);
});
```

Esse código dá um erro de compilação:

> local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final

Isso acontece porque variáveis declaradas fora de um *lambda* [só podem ser usadas dentro dele se forem `final`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34866143). Mas se eu declará-la como `final`:

```
final double valor = 0.0;
```

Aí eu não posso modificá-la, e o código dá outro erro:

> cannot assign a value to final variable valor

Enfim, se você quer sumarizar resultados, um *loop* tradicional já resolve.

---

Mas se quiser, também pode usar *streams*, uma alternativa é fazer assim:

```
double valor = produtos
    // cria o stream
    .stream()
    // obtém os valores das vendas de todos os produtos
    .mapToDouble(produto -> produto.getValor(Venda.class))
    // soma tudo
    .sum();
```

Com isso, `valor` terá a soma dos valores, ou zero caso a lista de produtos seja vazia.

Só lembrando que *streams* são legais, mas [têm o seu custo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22670380) e geralmente [serão mais lentas que um *loop* tradicional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/361945/112052), e temos que balancear a clareza do código e [outros benefícios](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/223498/112052) que as *streams* trazem (vai da opinião de cada um) versus a velocidade. Claro que para casos simples como esse talvez nem faça tanta diferença, mas é algo a se considerar sempre.

Comment: Faz todo sentido. Desculpe a demora, deixei isso de lado por algumas semanas.

Answer (score 1):

Lucas.

Não sei se o forEach é uma boa opção pra somar valor, e também nem consegui fazer usando ele.

O que eu normalmente uso é retornar uma stream, usar um map pra pegar os valores e um reduce depois, pra somar tudo:

```
double valor = lista.stream().map(x -> x.getValor()).reduce((x,y) -> x + y).orElse(0.0);
```

Como eu não sou nenhum conhecedor do Java 8, provavelmente deve ter jeitos mais eficientes.

Answer (score -1):

*Usando um foreach simples:*

```
  private double getValorVenda() {
    double valor = 0.0;
    for (Produto produto : produtos) {
      valor += produto.getValor(Venda.class);
    }
    return valor;
  }
```

*Ou usando expressão lambda:*

```
  private double getValorVenda(){
    final double[] valor= {0};
    
    produtos.forEach(produto -> valor[0] += produto.getValor(Venda.class));
    return valor[0];
  }
```