# Utilizando IntUnaryOperator Interface em Java para retornar n funções

Tags: java, expressões-lambda

Estou lendo a documentação dessa livraria que está no título.

Quero implementar um método que retorna uma composição de funções, se eu não por argumentos deve retornar a função identidade, se for 1 deve retornar apenas a função, se for n>1 deve retornar a todas as funções, como o exemplo:

```
1 IntUnaryOperator[] functions = {
2 compose(),
3 compose(x -> x+1),
4 compose(x -> x*2, x -> x+1),
5 compose(x -> x+1, x -> x*2),
6 compose(x -> x+1, x -> x*2, x -> x+1)
7 };
8 for (IntUnaryOperator f : functions) System.out.println(f.applyAsInt(1));
9 // Resultado esperado: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Imagino que devo começar assim, mas não sei como utilizar das funções lambdas coerentemente ainda, preciso de uma intuição de como prosseguir.

```java
import java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator;

public class IntOperatorsUtil {

  public static IntUnaryOperator compose(IntUnaryOperator... functions) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma alternativa [à sua solução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/427242/112052) é criar uma *stream* com as funções e usar o [método `Stream::reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) para retornar uma composição de todas as funções:

```
public static IntUnaryOperator compose(IntUnaryOperator... functions) {
    return Arrays.stream(functions).reduce(IntUnaryOperator.identity(), IntUnaryOperator::compose);
}
```

Repare também que usei o [método `IntUnaryOperator::identity`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntUnaryOperator.html#identity--), que já retorna a função identidade (tudo bem que é trivial criar outra, mas se já tem algo pronto, por que não usar?)

O `reduce` acima é equivalente [ao *loop* que você fez](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/427242/112052): o valor inicial é a função identidade, e ele vai chamando o método `compose` com as demais funções.

---

Outra opção - semanticamente equivalente - é:

```
public static IntUnaryOperator compose(IntUnaryOperator... functions) {
    return Arrays.stream(functions).reduce(IntUnaryOperator::compose)
        .orElse(IntUnaryOperator.identity());
}
```

Neste caso, o [`reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) retorna um [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html). Nele usamos o [método `orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) para retornar a função identidade caso não haja funções a serem compostas.

---

Lembrando que [*streams* têm o seu custo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22670380) e no geral [serão mais lentas que um *loop* tradicional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/361945/112052). Você deve balancear a velocidade (caso seja de fato um problema) versus a clareza/concisão do código e [outros benefícios que as *streams* podem trazer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/223498/112052) (vai da opinião de cada um, claro). Talvez para programas pequenos nem faça tanta diferença, mas para sistemas maiores é algo a se considerar.

Comment: muito obrigado, me interessei na solução e vou estudar sobre stream

Answer (score 1):

Consegui obter o que queria, se for util a alguém no futuro:

```java
  public static IntUnaryOperator compose(IntUnaryOperator... functions) {
    IntUnaryOperator toReturn = x -> x;
    for (IntUnaryOperator f : functions) {   
         toReturn = toReturn.compose(f);
    };
    return toReturn;
  }
```